# Grouping by country and discipline in SQLServer

Tags: sql, sql-server

i've got a problem I cannot solve in SQLServer. There are 3 tables with data about the Olympics.

Table 1: Dysciplines - contains DisciplineID (int,PK) and Discipline (varchar)

Table 2: Athletes - contains AthleteID (int, FK), Athlete (varchar, PK), Nationality (varchar) and DisciplineID(int,FK)

Table3: Medals - contains AthleteID(int, PK), Year(int) and Medals(int)

I want to extract all the countries, that got more medals in their best discipline than in all the others combined. However, I am having problem with it.

Obviously I joined all the tables, but I'm not sure how do I continue. I tried:

```
WHERE MAX(SUM(dbo.Medals.Medals))>SUM(dbo.Medals.Medals)-MAX(SUM(dbo.Medals.Medals))
GROUP BY tab1.Dyscypline
```

But this is clearly wrong. I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Provide sample data and expected output, that would help us to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use aggregation and `having`.  Start with the number of medals in each discipline in each country:

```
select a.nationality, a.disclipineid, count(*) as num_medals
from athletes a join
     medals m
     on a.AthleteID = m.AthleteID
group by a.nationality, a.disclipineid;
```

Then aggregate again:

```
select nationality
from (select a.nationality, a.disclipineid, count(*) as num_medals
      from athletes a join
           medals m
           on a.AthleteID = m.AthleteID
      group by a.nationality, a.disclipineid
     ) am
group by nationality
having max(num_medals) > sum(num_medals) * 0.5;
```

That is, the maximum number of medals for a discpline accounts for more than half the medals.